# matrix in row of rdd to dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

First off sorry for the winded explanation.

Hi There, I am trying to converts some data (in form of RDD) to a dataframe but it's a bit more complex that just that.

I have an RDD: where each item is ROW() with a matrix (list of lists) called features and a list called labels.

I want to convert this RDD to a Dataframe where each row is a single list of features and a scalar which is the label. As you can see the problem arises in that the features in the RDD consists of matrix's rather then vectors.

Thanks,

Comment: I would try to go step by step, first convert your RDD to a DF, then do the operation of the DF... no?

Comment: What operation would expand the elements in the Row() to multiple elements  though?

Comment: map, forEach...

Answer (score 0):

```
flatMap(lambda row: [(f,l) for f, l in zip(row.feature, row.label)])
```

solution was to flatMap the features and labels for each row. (On RDD's)